# How to properly use the 'not()' operator in Python

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Learning how to code in Python (again) for which I am working on this simple word guessing game. The code (written below) is from a YouTube video I have been following (freeCodeCamp's Learn Python - Full Course for Beginners [Tutorial]).

What I don't understand is how `not(guesses_complete)` logically makes sense in this is code.

From my understanding, the code implies that the `while` loop executes and continues as long as the player's guess is not the secret word and the boolean value of `guesses_complete` is True (because the initial value of `guesses_complete` is False, so `not()` means the value has to be True to execute).

But the initial value of `guesses_complete` is set to False, so the `while` loop shouldn't execute at all.

```
# The player gets 3 chances to guess the secret word
# If guessed correctly within the given chances, the player wins
# If guessed incorrectly and there are no more chances, the player loses

secret_word = "Red"
guess = ""
counter = 0
guess_limit = 3
guesses_complete = False

while guess != secret_word and not(guesses_complete):
    if counter < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")
        counter += 1
    else:
        guesses_complete = True

if guesses_complete:
    print("Loser")
else:
    print("Winner")
```

The code works written as it is, but I don't know why. I'm pretty sure it's just that my understanding of the `not()` operator is weak. I'd highly appreciate it if someone clears this up for me.

Comment: First, `not(guesses_complete)` is equivalent to `not guesses_complete`. Secondly, [`not`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) is a Boolean operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `not()` works is indeed the contrary to what you are thinking. `not(guesses_complete)` in this case would be the same as using `guesses_complete == False`. If `guesses_complete == False`, this statement would return `True`, meaning the while loop should be executed. This same happens with `not(guesses_complete)` when the value of `guesses_complete` is set to `False`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thinking of ```not(guesses_complete)``` as the same thing as ```guesses_complete == False``` really helps with my thinking

Answer (score 1):

I believe the not() operator evaluates to the opposite. So if it set to false it switches the variable too true, and if the initial variable value is true the not() sets it too false. I think of it as an opposite day function.

Answer (score 1):

The not keyword is a logical operator. The return value will be True if the statement(s) is not True and the return value will be False if the statement(s) is not False. [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_not.asp). In the code above, we want the user to play until he has some guesses remaining i.e., we want the loop to execute if `guesses_complete` is False.

Answer (score 0):

The `not` key word inverts a boolean (true or false value), turning `True` into `False`. What this means is that if you want a piece of code to run if a variable is false than by using `not` you can make that run. Example to help:

```
finished_game = False
while not finished_game:#While the game isn't finished
    #run game code
```

Does that make sense? In my experience the `not` keyword means you can use `False` as `True`.

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Oh I wasn't thinking of it that way. I was thinking along the lines of, ```not``` checks if the the boolean value is the opposite of what is written in the code and only then executes the code. Instead, I should be thinkin of it as ```not``` executes the code if the boolean value is ```False```